# How to write OSX finder new functionality/view

Tags: macos, plugins, finder

I am new to Mac programming and I wan't to make a sort of plugin that change the standart view of files in Finder and add some custom buttons.
Any idea how can I accomplish it or where to start?
Thanks a lot,
Adam

Comment: I take back my earlier (ignorant) statement. Compare to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin which appears to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

To add custom buttons: build them and put in app bundle. Then drag your .app to toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. Part of the question was how do I change the view of files, you know - icons, list, columns, cover flow..., which is more important for me now. Thanks a lot everybody for startup hint..