# How do I add items to the Finder context menu in Mac OS X using JAVA?

Tags: java, macos, contextmenu

I'm trying to port Java application to Mac OS, My program needs to add items to Finder context menu, Is there a way to add items **using Java**?

Thanks

Comment: The answer, I believe, is no, you cannot do this just with Java code.  You can create entries in the `/Library/Contextual Menu Items/` path but what exists there is in Mac binary format.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin

Comment: Is there work arounds? I mean write it in other language and call it in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question, but for prosperity, I'd like to try to answer this.

The [Liferay Nativity](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity) (Java) library is a cross-platform way of programatically adding icon overlays and context menus to file browsers, for Mac, Windows and Linux.

On Mac, [Liferay Nativity](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity) relies on the Objective-C-based '[Finder Sync](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FinderSync/Reference/FinderSync_Framework)' framework:

- [Finder Sync overview (Mac OSX)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html)
- [Finder Sync API Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FinderSync/Reference/FinderSync_Framework)