# FLOSS that implements badging and contextual menu in Snow Leopard's Finder

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard, contextmenu, finder

Apparently with Snow Leopard, due to rewrite of Finder in Cocoa and removal of Contextual Menu Plugins, it is no longer trivial to do either badging nor contextual menus, however [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) seems to both add a contextual menu in the managed folder, and add status badges.

Is there an open source project that managed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been years since this question was asked, but here's (almost) exactly what you were asking for: FLOSS that implements badging and contextual menus, but only for Lion and Mountain Lion (but I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to adapt it for Snow Leopard if still needed).

[Liferay Nativity](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity) provides a scripting bundle that will swizzle the relevant Finder methods and a Java client for setting the icons and context menus. It also includes equivalent projects for Windows and Linux.

The project is open source under LGPL, so feel free to contribute any bug fixes or improvements!

Comment: Praise the FSM -- no matter how old the question is, the answer is still highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think Dropbox may have reverse engineered Finder if I recall their comments at PyCon. The [full video](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/4878722/) is online and the slide is 16 minutes in.

Comment: I've heard about that, but I'm asking about concrete example of an opensource project that implements the same or similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to inject code into the Finder process and override objective C methods in the Finder process. refer [How to Write OS X Finder plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin) post.