# Generate "Finder.h" for a SIMBL plugin

Tags: macos, finder, simbl

I'm trying to create a SIMBL plugin for Finder to add icon overlay over some files.

I have this code:

```
@implementation NSObject (FAIconOverlay)

- (void)FAIconOverlay_TIconAndTextCell_drawIconWithFrame:(struct CGRect)arg1
{
    [self FAIconOverlay_TIconAndTextCell_drawIconWithFrame:arg1];

    if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(node)]) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSClassFromString(@"FINode") nodeWithFENode:[(TNodeIconAndNameCell *)self node]] fullPath] lastPathComponent]);

    // Draw the icon overlay
}

- (void)FAIconOverlay_TDesktopIcon_drawIconInContext:(struct CGContext *)arg1
{    
    [self FAIconOverlay_TDesktopIcon_drawIconInContext:arg1];
}

@end
```

I can draw the icon overlay but, when I try to get the path of the file I get a "Use of undeclared identifier TNodeIconAndNameCell". Looking this link < [How to Write OS X Finder plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin/8782596#8782596) > I see that is neccessary to generate a Finder.h file...

My question is: How to generate this file?? I tried running "class-dump -H Finder.app" but I get too more compiling errors

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not include all the headers generated by class-dump (to now how to generate this headers check the @jackjr300 answer). Only is necessary included the used headers and fix the compiling problems.

Answer (score 4):

To create a "**Finder.h**" :

```
sudo class-dump -H -o /output_directory/Path  /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the drawIconWithFrame: method of TIconAndTextCell, you should override the drawIconWithFrame: method of TNodeIconAndNameCell.

```
Class finder_class = [objc_getClass("TNodeIconAndNameCell") class];

class_addMethod(finder_class, @selector(FT_drawIconWithFrame:),
                class_getMethodImplementation(self_class, @selector(FT_drawIconWithFrame:)),"v@:{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}");

old = class_getInstanceMethod(finder_class, @selector(drawIconWithFrame:));
new = class_getInstanceMethod(finder_class, @selector(FT_drawIconWithFrame:));
method_exchangeImplementations(old, new);
```

And then you can do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSClassFromString(@"FINode") nodeWithFENode:[self node]] fullPath] lastPathComponent]);
```