# Icon Overlay on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder

I try to add Icon Overlay on mac like Dropbox !
I already search, i try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin/8782596#8782596)

With SIMBL Plugin so i follow the quick tuto on how I make SIMBL Plugin [here](http://code.google.com/p/simbl/wiki/Tutorial)

And like Les Nie said i try to get all the Finder's headers with class-dump
I try this :

```
./class-dump -H /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/FinderKit
```

But I get some error with Les Nie code !

does anybody know what is :

```
struct TNSRef<id> _parent;
```

I get this error :

```
Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
```

Does someone has already manages to add Overlay Icon on Mac OS-X Lion ?
And I know if i did this i will not appear on App store like dropbox !

Thank you,

Comment: "some error" isn't really anything to go on....

Comment: I'm trying the same and found out, that dropbox (as well as google drive) does this with mach inject (https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star)

Comment: Some error like Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers for the file FI_TTextCell.h with the line "struct TNSRef< NSColor *> _enabledTextColor;" , I will try mach_inject thx Jonas

Comment: Finally I didn't have to do this on Mac 10.5 ^^ So i'm stuck with SIMBL now

Comment: @jonas-schnelli Have you had any success using mach_inject for this?

Comment: nope (so far). But i've agreed to not use hacking-finder techniques. :)