# Cocoa : How to intercept a right click on a free (no icon) area of the desktop?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, mouse, desktop

I would like my app to react to a right mouse click on a free (no icon, other app window, ...) area of the desktop.
Thank you if you can help me.

Steven

Comment: Right click on finder ?

Comment: desktop of the finder yes...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inject code (finder plugin) inside the finder application.
Write finder plugin with [method swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling). and use [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject) framework to inject that plugin into finder.
Take a look at [How to Write OS X Finder plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but method is looking complex... There must be a simpler solution.

Comment: Any other possibility please?